# Determine the Top 10 biggest numbers

Tags: delphi

I have 4 databases. All containing the same members with scores from different matches of target shooting. I want to determine the overall top 10 highest scores. I then add the scores from the first DB to an array, I then add the scores of the members from the second DB to the array(adding the scores). And so on until the last. How do I then get the 10 biggest scores? I have looked sorting arrays. I think my solutions lies there.

Comment: I rarely ask this on SO, but what have you tried? -1

Comment: Search your array for the biggest score using a `for` loop. Inside the loop: `if arr[I] > s1 then begin s1 := arr[I]; s1Index := I; end;` So at the end of the loop `s1` will be the biggest score, and `s1Index` the position of that score. Now when you want the 2nd biggest score, you must **first delete the biggest** (because you don't want to find it again). And then repeat the above to search for the biggest. Keep repeating for `s3, s4,...` etc. _When you get appropriately marked for your creative and fast solution, you'll understand the benefit of doing **zero research** before asking on SO._

Comment: Yes I have tried.

Comment: @Stefan He didn't ask whether you tried something. He asked **what** you tried. So [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40069305/edit) your question and explain **what** you tried. No offence, but I have no reason to believe you when you claim "you have tried". My grandmother always taught me: never trust a stranger on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

Your database engine can do this work in the best way - just execute query like this:

```
 SELECT name, score FROM membertable ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

If you already have got all data in array, apply [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm to get 10 best values (without full sorting)

Comment: Query part of answer is very low quality because (a) ignores array part of Q (b) assumes SQL database (c) uses wacky proprietary syntax. I don't get why so many votes...

Comment: @Free Consulting a) I supposed one of the best solution (from algor. POV) for an array b) author did not described database details, but he must know that brute-force using of DB is wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the code I used:

```
For I := 0 to iCount -2 do               //iCount is length of DB   
       for J := I+1 to iCount -1 do 
        if arrScore[I] < arrScore[J] then
       begin
         T := arrScore[I];
         K := arrMember[I];
         arrScore[I] := arrScore[J];// arrScore holds member's score
         arrMember[I] := arrMember[J];// arrMember holds member's name
         arrScore[J] := T;
         arrMember[J] := K;
       end;
```

And it works, thanks to all your answers.